# Can anyone help me to find what is wrong in below code?

Tags: java

I am not getting updated list from a method passed a references

```
    List<Person> beans = new ArrayList<Person>();
    boolean alreadyPresent = isPersonPresentOnSolr(solrServer, beans);

    // beans.size() is zero
    boolean isPersonPresentOnSolr(SolrServer solrServer, List<Person> beans)
   {
    QueryResponse response   = solrServer.query(solrQry);                
    beans = response.getBeans(Person.class);

    //beans.size()  is 5
   }
```

Comment: not enought information. Use debugger.

Comment: I am passing empty list to a method as parameter and populating it inside method. I am able to see updated list inside method using debugger but getting empty list outside method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not do

```
beans = response.getBeans(Person.class); // you lost reference of object. it is c++ way,
//but not works for java
```

you should do

```
List<Person> newBeans = response.getBeans(Person.class);
beans.addAll(newBeans);
```

Comment: but I am able to see same list updated inside method and loose all reference once pointer goes out from method

Comment: as I explained, it is c++ way. this is not pointer exactly. think about, "main beans" points 0x1000 address. in "function beans", first, it points 0x1000 address too. then you call response.getBeans. and it creates a new object and points 0x1001. and you assign it to "function beans". so "function beans" points 0x1001. when you look it in debugger, you see 5 items in 0x1001, because "function beans" points 0x1001. but "main beans" still points 0x1000. so, you need to copy elements from 0x1001 to 0x1000, or you need to change address "main beans" pointed to 0x1001

Comment: Thanks Adem for details info.